# Arduino Serial.readBytes giving incorrect values

Tags: serialization, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to make a mobile app that can control some RGB lights that I'm using with my arduino. Right now, I am trying to add functionality to control the LED brightness using a slider. I am sending information using bluetooth over serial, and currently I am sending an identifier along with the brightness value as a string. As an example: "BRT55" where BRT is the identifier for brightness, and 55 is the value at which to set it to. I am doing this so I know which task to do, as sending just an integer wouldn't be very helpful if I also may want to control individual RGB values, or change patterns. Right now the information I am receiving seems close to correct, but is not. The serial output shows this:

```
;BR
BRT
BRA
RTB
TCB
TBB
TAB
T@B
T?B
T=B
T:B
T8B
T6B
T5B
T4B
```

Here is the code that I'm running:

```cpp
if (Serial.available()) {
    // First lets reset our variables each pass
    rcvIdent = "";
    rcvData[4] = {};
    // Reading input data and storing to byte array
    Serial.readBytes(rcvData, 4);
    // Iterate through and determine what operation to do next.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rcvIdent += (char) rcvData[i];
    }
    Serial.println(rcvIdent); // Should be "BRT"
```

I know the problem has something to do with the buffer not resetting, I'm pretty sure all the values being sent are correct but in the wrong order. I am unsure how to get them in the correct order every single iteration.

Here is the code I am using to send the values out from the app:

```cpp
try
{
    //Console.WriteLine(e.Progress + 1);
    //myConnection.thisSocket.OutputStream.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(e.Progress + 1));
    byte[] charArr = new byte[] { (byte)'B', (byte)'R', (byte)'T', (byte)e.Progress};
    myConnection.thisSocket.OutputStream.Write(charArr);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Comment: You need to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and reform your post.  DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. (or links to such images).

Comment: `The serial output shows this` ... that's not useful without a `The serial output should show this`

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems. Firstly you send message every 10ms and you are expect arrive this in same timing to arduino. But this is a faulty assumption. BT transmit data in packets and OS collect sending data to buffer, then send full packet not only 5 chars. You don't have any synchronization in your message. So than your arduino loss some chars and output is shifting.

Second. You have wrong conversion number to string in `e.Progress`. It's seems as you are sends binary form of numbers.

Solution is add message delimiter char (for example CR or LF or both) and write much complicate loop for handling arrived chars, which can deal with the interruption of data transmission in any place.

And of course - DO NOT post images of code as said sawdust